# swift multiple views to tap gestures in array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have an image slider where multiple images are added to a scrollview.  Each is stored in an array of my custom data type (named Slide).  I cycle through them like this:

```
    for (index, slide) in slides.enumerated() {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: slide.image)       //set the imageView with the imageName in this slide
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let xPos = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(index)   //calculate x depending upon slide index
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: -200, width: self.SVSlider.frame.width, height: self.SVSlider.frame.height)
        SVSlider.contentSize.width = SVSlider.frame.width * CGFloat(index + 1)  //add slide image to scrollview
        SVSlider.addSubview(imageView)

        //add tap function to slide
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.tag = index
        let tapImage = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(slideAction(_:)))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapImage)
    }
```

Each slide image is attached to the method "slideAction", below:

```
@objc func slideAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let selName = slides[(sender.view?.tag)!].target
    NSObject.perform(Selector(selName))
}
```

But the application throws an error when I click an image.  By debugging I can see that the "tag" is correctly set to the slide index number.  I want to perform the target action held in the slide object.  (Currently the target is a String of the method name - ending with ':').

**How can I get the "slideAction" to goto the method in the slide object?**

Comment: Your array slides is a custom class, am I right? It contains more than images in it, correct?

Comment: Yes, 'my custom data type (named Slide)' contain a string name of the image and another string of the slide's intended target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ,create target method in the custom class  `callMethodDirectly` and call it

```
@objc func slideAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let selName = slides[(sender.view?.tag)!]  
    selName.callMethodDirectly()
}

class slide:NSObjcet
{
  func callMethodDirectly()
  {  
     // implement target code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Got a warning and an error!  Where is the slide's target gone?  (warning: Forced cast of 'Slide' to same type has no effect;  error: Value of type 'Slide' has no member 'callMethodDirectly')

Comment: Add callMethodDirectly as a function in the slide class

Comment: Oh I see.  However I already have method (that is also used by another button).  So is there a way to call that?

Comment: from that object you can call any method in the class assuming you send the parameters

Comment: Just to be clear, how do I write my data structure?  eg. var slide1 = Slide(imageName: "pic1", callMethodDirectly: {myMethod()}. Is that right? Also how can I call myMethod (_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer), should I use (nil) as parameter (in the above var)?